# Getting correct path/url from Paperclip Gem during after_post_process callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a fairly standard Paperclip setup, it's almost straight out of the readme. I have a simple method triggered via callback to get the primary colors out of an uploaded image, and save them to the corresponding instance.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :file, :styles => { large: "800x>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    after_post_process :get_colors

    def get_colors
      colors = Miro::DominantColors.new(self.file.url)
      colors = colors.to_hex.join(',')
      self.colors = colors
      self.save       
    end
end
```

As you can see, I have an `after_post_process` callback, and it does get triggered. The trouble is that when I call `self.file.url` I get a path that looks like this:

`"/system/images/files//original/Peterson-Products-Wireframe-v01.jpg?1398443345"`.

It's missing the `:id_partion` portion. It's real path should look more like:

`"/system/images/files/000/000/033/original/Peterson-Products-Wireframe-v01.jpg?1398443345"`

Should I be using some other callback? I only want this triggered once per upload... Never again if the image is updated. Is this a bug in paperclip that I should be filing on Github?

- Rails Version 4.1
- Paperclip Version 4.1
- Ruby 2.1.0

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

try **queued_for_write**

```
colors = Miro::DominantColors.new(file.queued_for_write[:original].path)
```